# Continuous uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

I need help to demonstrate the following or if you find a function I would appreciate it, I have already looked for many functions to see if any one fulfills it but none works for me and I can't think of how to prove it, I mean try to do it by defining uniform continuity and do not reach anything.

"Is there a growing function $ f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow {\mathbb {R}}$ such that neither she nor her inverse are uniformly continuous? If such a function exists, if not, demonstrate because it is not possible. "

First of all, Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of the inverse, do you know any example that is not uniformly continuous on the interval $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, the exponential function.

Comment: What is the definition of  a growing function?

Comment: Do you want at add continuity of $f$ as a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider something like:

$f(x) = x^2 + c1(n)$, for all 2n < x < 2n + 1

$f(x) = x^\frac{1}{2} + c2(n)$, for all 2n + 1 < x < 2n + 2

n - integers starting 0

c1(n) and c2(n) - some constant values

just think if you can find some function like that, define it for all integer x and make it growing (and even continuous), also think if this function can help you

Comment: Such functions are not monotonic. Doesn't growing mean increasing? Actually 'growing'is not an accepted term at all.

Comment: I edited, this was not clear, constants may change on each interval